# scrollview is not working

Tags: android, list

I got a list in my main but problem is that when I scan the barcodes for more than 15 barcodes, then it didn't show the"scan" button already and I tried to use the scroll view for that but it is not working :
Any helps?

```
     <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:fillViewport="true">
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />
          <ListView 
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 


/>
<TextView 
  android:id="@android:id/empty"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
  android:text="no notes"
   />
<Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="scan"/>




</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally it is a bad idea to place a listview inside of the scrollview.  It doesn't work as expected.  See the following post:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-beginners/LRpLgGOy2Pc

Answer (score 1):

In Android it's not possible to use a ListView in a ScrollView. In order to achieve the same result you can use a ListView and add a header and a footer.

[addHeaderView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#addHeaderView%28android.view.View,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean%29)

You can use a ListActivity. Create one xml layout file for your header and add it to the ListView: (put the Code in your `onCreate()` function before calling `setAdapter()`)

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
getListView().addHeaderView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.header, null));
getListView().addFooterView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.footer, null));
```

The footer works exactly the same way.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your code, but I have one wonder, I didn't use ListAdapter, but just listView , seems like I have no choice but to use ListAdapteR?

Comment: It doesn't matter how you add your items, the part with header and footer is important.

Comment: Thanks flo, I think I better show the Java Code as well because I am more and more confused .....

Answer (score 0):

Hi, you can use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) instead of LinearLayout.

In such case you should place your button at the bottom of the layout. After that other controls should be placed above the button. RelativeLayout has special xml-attributes to help you do this. After that you do not need a ScrollView.

Comment: Hi do you mean that I use only RelativeLayout without LinearLayout?

Comment: I believe I ve alr tired that one but it is just showing me the error message and the app crush but i will try it again

Comment: I mean, you should delete `ScrollView`, and replace `LinearLayout` with `RelativeLayout`